# Slider Control arrows are moving

Tags: html, css

I have created an only CSS slider, couple of days ago and its seems the control arrows are positioned well when I open the page on my computer but they are moving when I zoom in or out on the page.How can I keep them always in position?
I can't figure out what I missing.

Here is the test page:
http://friendshipforever.co.uk/slider%20test/slider.html

CSS and HTML below:

```css
#slider {
 text-align: center;
}

h2 {
 margin: 40px 0 25px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
 padding: 0 0 10px;
}

p {
 margin: 0 0 16px;
}

strong { 
 font-weight: bold;
}

label, a {
 color: teal;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
}
label:hover, a:hover {
 color: #000 !important;
}
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
label, #active, img { -moz-user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none; }
.catch { display: block; height: 0; overflow: hidden; }
#slider {
 margin: 0 auto;
}
#description {
 margin: 25px auto;
 text-align: left;
 max-width: 650px;
 padding: 0 25px;
}
.respond {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 370px;
}


/* NEW EXPERIMENT */
/* Slider Setup */


input {
 display: none;
}

#slide1:checked ~ #slides .inner { margin-left:0; }
#slide2:checked ~ #slides .inner { margin-left:-100%; }
#slide3:checked ~ #slides .inner { margin-left:-200%; }
#slide4:checked ~ #slides .inner { margin-left:-300%; }
#slide5:checked ~ #slides .inner { margin-left:-400%; }


#overflow {
 width: 105%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

article img {
 max-width: 400px;
}

#slides .inner {
 width: 500%;
 line-height: 0;
}

#slides article {
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
}

/* Slider Styling */

/* Control Setup */

#controls {
 margin: -25% 0 0 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
}

#controls label { 
 display: none;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 opacity: 0.3;
}

#active {
 margin: 23% 0 0;
 text-align: center;
}

#active label img {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 70px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 3px;
 border-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
#active label img:hover {
opacity: 0.5; 
}



#controls label:hover {
 opacity: 0.8;
}

#slide1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2), 
#slide2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3), 
#slide3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4), 
#slide4:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(5), 
#slide5:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1) {
 background: url('next.png') no-repeat;
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 margin: 0 350px 0 0;
 display: block;
}


#slide1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(5),
#slide2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1),
#slide3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2),
#slide4:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3),
#slide5:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4) {
 background: url('prev.png') no-repeat;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 0 300px;
 display: block;
}


#slide1:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(1),
#slide2:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(2),
#slide3:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(3),
#slide4:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(4),
#slide5:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(5) {
 opacity: 0.5;


}




/* Slider Styling */

#slides {
 
 width:400px;
 margin: auto;
 
 
}


/* Animation */

#slides .inner {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 -webkit-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
 -moz-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
    -ms-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
     -o-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
        transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); /* easeInOutQuart */

 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
 -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
    -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
     -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); /* easeInOutQuart */
}

#slider {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

#controls label{
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
 transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
}

#slide1:checked ~ #slides article:nth-child(1) .info,
#slide2:checked ~ #slides article:nth-child(2) .info,
#slide3:checked ~ #slides article:nth-child(3) .info,
#slide4:checked ~ #slides article:nth-child(4) .info,
#slide5:checked ~ #slides article:nth-child(5) .info {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out 0.6s;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out 0.6s;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease-out 0.6s;
 transition: all 1s ease-out 0.6s;
}

.info, #controls, #slides, #active, #active label, .info h3, .desktop, .tablet, .mobile {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!-- CSS -->
 <link href="sliderstyle.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

   
  <!-- Slider Setup -->
 
  <input checked type=radio name=slider id=slide1 />
  <input type=radio name=slider id=slide2 />
  <input type=radio name=slider id=slide3 />
  <input type=radio name=slider id=slide4 />
  <input type=radio name=slider id=slide5 />
 
 
  <!-- The Slider -->
  
  <div id=slides>
  
   <div id=overflow>
   
    <div class=inner>
    
     <article>
      
      <img src=cheesesandwich.png />
     </article>
     
     <article>
      
      <img src=cheeseplush1.jpg />
     </article>
     
     <article>
      
      <img src=cheeseplush2.jpg />
     </article>
     
     <article>
     
      <img src=cheeseplush3.jpg />
     </article>
     
     <article>
      
      <img src=cheeseplush4.jpg />
     </article>
     
    </div> <!-- .inner -->
    
   </div> <!-- #overflow -->
  
  </div> <!-- #slides -->
 
 
  <!-- Controls and Active Slide Display -->
 
  <div id=controls>

   <label for=slide1></label>
   <label for=slide2></label>
   <label for=slide3></label>
   <label for=slide4></label>
   <label for=slide5></label>
  
  </div> <!-- #controls -->
  
  <div id=active>

   <label for=slide1><img src=cheesesandwich.png /></label>
   <label for=slide2><img src=cheeseplush1.jpg /></label>
   <label for=slide3><img src=cheeseplush2.jpg /></label>
   <label for=slide4><img src=cheeseplush3.jpg /></label>
   <label for=slide5><img src=cheeseplush4.jpg /></label>
   
  </div> <!-- #active -->
 
 </article> <!-- #slider -->
```

Answer (score 0):

remove margin

```
#controls {
    height: 50px;
    /*margin: -25% 0 0;*/
    width: 100%;
}
#active {
    /*margin: 23% 0 0;*/
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: they are still moving after I removed margin as you mentioned